# sass-rails image-path & asset-path showing incorrect path for image when asset host provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, sass

When using the image-path helper method in sass-rails

An scss statement like this:

```
  image-url('logo.png');
```

generates a weird url like this:

```
"//www3.myassets.com/assets/logo.png
```

where the www3.myassets.com is coming from the asset host property set on the environment.

Why is this happening? I expect the following output:

```
  "/logo.png"
```

It might not be relevant but we also have compass on the project, although my investigations lead me to believe that the compass method is not the one being used.

Answer (score 0):

1. The url is not weird. Skippng the protocol allows the browser to use the same protocol the page is in, so a page loaded with http will load assets with http, and a page loaded with https, will load the assets using https.
2. As in rails, `image_url` and `image_path` mean exactly that, the former is a complete URL, and the latter is just a relative path (relative as URL, it is normally an absolute path within the web server)